# Plot histogram from vector of counts

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, matlab-hg2

If I have a vector of histogram edges and bin counts, is it possible to use this to directly generate a histogram plot?

For example, given data vectors

```
edges = 0:10; % histogram edges for 9 bins
counts = round(normpdf(edges(1:end-1), 5, 2) * 1000) % Generate bin counts

counts =

     9    27    65   121   176   199   176   121    65    27
```

I can always generate the data artificially as

```
data = [];
for i = 1:numel(counts)
  % This should be optimised by pre-allocating the data array,
  % but this is only provided as an example.
  data = [data (ones(1, counts(i)) * mean(edges(i:i+1)))];
end
```

so that `numel(data) == sum(counts)` and I can then plot the histogram using `histogram(data, edges)`:

[image]

However, I would like to do this without having to do the intermediary step of generating the artificial data as this seems rather convoluted.

I know that I could use the `bar` function, but I would prefer to use `histogram` because I prefer the way that it plots and the functionality that it offers.

**Edit:** I'm using MATLAB R2015a / R2015b, although I would prefer to maintain backward compatibility with R2015a if possible (I know that there were fairly major changes to `histogram` in R2015b).

Comment: Why you dont like bar? histogram computes the counts and then calls bar....

Comment: @AnderBiguri, are you sure about that? `bar` returns a Bar object and `histogram` returns a [Histogram](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/histogram-object.html) object which are both primitives. The Histogram object has nice properties such as `FaceAlpha` that are not available in `bar`. Perhaps `hist` used to use `bar` internally, but I'm fairly sure that `histogram` (introduced in R2014b) reimplemented the functionality from scratch.

Comment: I would use patch for this.

Comment: I literally see no difference between your plot and this one:
http://oi62.tinypic.com/34z0m5u.jpg
when using the bar function with your data set:

new_edges=(edges(1:10)+0.5)
bar(new_edges,counts,1)

But if you insist on using histogram, than I really don't have any idea :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can circumvent feeding the actual data to a `Histogram` object. The functionality of the `Histogram` object includes being able to change bins/edges after the fact, and for that it needs to know its source data.

Comment: Unfortunately I think that this is the right answer :(